# Conditional form validation with Yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am beginner in Yup and I need to do some form validation with Yup. Here is an example of my schema :

```
    const MyFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
       contactId: Yup.string().required(),
       phoneNumber : Yup.string().phoneNumber().required(),
       email: Yup.string().email().required()
    });
```

My form is valid in 2 cases : either the user enters the contactID or he enters the phoneNumber and the email.

I tried to implement this using `test` function but was unable to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the same logic for rest 2 fields:

```
Yup.object().shape({
    contactId: Yup.string().when(["phoneNumber", "email"], {
      is: (phoneNumber, email) => !phoneNumber || !email,
      then: Yup.string().required()
    }),
    phoneNumber: Yup.string().when("contractId", {
      is: contactId => !!contactId,
      then: Yup.string().required()
    }),
    email: Yup.string().when("contractId", {
      is: contactId => !!contactId,
      then: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required()
    })
});
```

To check for email, you can use built in function **Yup.email()**. For phone you need to build custom validator:

```
const PHONE_VALIDATOR = /...your RegEx here.../

...
phoneNumber : Yup.string().matches(PHONE_VALIDATOR, 'Phone is not valid').required()
```

Comment: How do we check that the phoneNumber or Email formats are valid ? Do I have to this on the then ?

Comment: I have made a unit test to validate your solution but it does not work. Maybe I am not seeing something, a here is a use case that I want to validate https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bell-1qpo8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark